# Why does Bootstrap Collapse keep removing the "collapse" class after expanding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [jQuery Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) on an element that's inserted via Ajax.

When I apply the line below, it removes the `collapse` class. I need the class to remain so I can call collapse('hide') when the Ajax content needs to be closed.

```
$ajaxContent.html(data).find('.collapse').collapse();
```

Here's what I have in my .php file:

```
<section class="collapse">
```

Here's what it ends up with after the jQuery is applied:

```
<section class="in" style="height: auto;">
```

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it so the collapse class doesn't get removed?

Comment: In this simple example it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Luuuef3j/1/
Can you make a jsFiddle demo with your code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @friedi nothing at all happens in your example, so not sure how it's working fine for you...

Comment: The class gets added. Have a look with firebug or developer tools.

Comment: @friedi which class gets added?

Comment: The class `in` gets added and the class `collapse` is still there.

Comment: @friedi you have a point there, yet the OP accepted my answer, consequently it's safe to assume that removing / renaming the class seems to have resolved the issue for them... however strange that may be... i updated my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid calling your element's class `collapse` as it's being used by the plugin. Call it something else (eg. give it an id of `collapse` instead of class) and it should work.

**EDIT**: Alternatively you can use the plugin via data attributes (`data-toggle="collapse"`); I'd still refrain from calling the element's class `collapse` to avoid confusion.

**EDIT #2**: Following @friedi's comment to the question, I had a look at the example provided on [Bootstrap's documentation on collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) and realized that they are actually using the `collapse` class too. Going out from the fact that you accepted my answer, I'm assuming that renaming / removing it still resolved the issue for you for some reason, but the origin of the issue may be laying somewhere else in your code (maybe another bit of js or the structure of your HTML, not sure).

**EDIT #3**: I think the culprit is probably in whatever your `data` variable is holding; I'm guessing that it doesn't have the class `collapse` added to whatever structure you're applying to `$ajaxContent` using the `html` function, and it's actually missing from there instead of it getting removed by the `collapse` function (which it is not, as it's not removing that class).